# Facebook avatar failed to download using Picasso in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, picasso

Hello I am trying to integrate the [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library in android. This is my URL which I am passing in the `load` method of Picasso.

URL : http://graph.facebook.com/244054592454345/picture?type=large

but `Picasso` onBitmapFailed method callback is calling that means it failed to download the bitmap and getting drawable value to null.

```
com.squareup.picasso.Target target = new com.squareup.picasso.Target() {

@Override
public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {
    userProfile.setBitmap(bitmap);
    // call the Web API to register the walker here
    new AudioStreetAsyncTask(getActivity(), userProfile, getString(R.string.registration_processing_message), new TaskCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTaskCompleted(String jsonResponse) {
           Log.d(TAG, jsonResponse);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable drawable) {
    userProfile.setBitmap(null);
    // call the Web API to register the walker here
    new AudioStreetAsyncTask(getActivity(), userProfile, getString(R.string.registration_processing_message), new TaskCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTaskCompleted(String jsonResponse) {
           Log.d(TAG, jsonResponse);
        }
    }).execute();
}

@Override
public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable drawable) {}
};

Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(imgUrl.toString()).into(target);
```

I could not trace the problem why it is failing even you can see URL is correct but it fails every time. Any idea ?

Comment: This is due to `http -> https`. It has been answered here https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/463

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Jake Wharton said It is redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS and your client probably isn't
handling that properly. Either request that URL with HTTPS so the redirect
stays on the same protocol or drop OkHttp into your app (it will follow the
cross-protocol redirect).

so either update your http protocol to https, it should work.

Or you can do like call this Web API to [https://graph.facebook.com/244054592454345/?fields=picture.type(large)](https://graph.facebook.com/244054592454345/?fields=picture.type%28large%29)

then you would get this JSON

```
{
   "picture": {
      "data": {
         "is_silhouette": false,
         "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/t1.0-1/s200x200/1472865_191408954385576_14109897_n.jpg"
      }
   },
   "id": "244054592454345"
}
```

then get the URL from this JSON and then use this URL to get facebook avatar of this user.

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/t1.0-1/s200x200/1472865_191408954385576_14109897_n.jpg").into(target);
```

Comment: Just use https (https://graph.facebook.com/244054592454345/picture?type=large) and it work with picassa.

Comment: Yup this I shared in my answer also :-)